# (CS0029) converter uma List em ObservableCollection || SQLite

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Estou tentando criar um método que retorne uma `ObservableCollection` no lugar de uma `List`no SQLite

```
namespace Projeto_03.DataBase
{
    public class TarefasDataAccess
    {
        private SQLiteConnection _database;

        public TarefasDataAccess()
        {
            _database = DependencyService.Get<IDatabase>().GetConnection();
            _database.CreateTable<Tarefa>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Tarefa> GetTarefas()//era List<Tarefa>
        {
            return _database.Table<Tarefa>.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

só que na linha que tenta retornar a lista `return _database.Table<Tarefa>.ToList();` Ocorre o erro:

`Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Projeto_03.Model.Tarefa>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Projeto_03.Model.Tarefa>`

```
namespace Projeto_03.ViewModel
{
    public partial class TelaPrincipalViewModel : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Tarefa> Tarefas { get; set; }//era List<Tarefa>

        public TelaPrincipalViewModel()
        {
            Tarefas = new TarefasDataAccess().GetTarefas();
        }
    }
}
```

se alguem puder ajudar. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só criar uma nova instância de **`ObservableCollection`** passando a lista como parâmetro.

```
public ObservableCollection<Tarefa> GetTarefas()
{
    return new ObservableCollection<Tarefa>(_database.Table<Tarefa>.ToList());
}
```